# SBT doesn't apply build.sbt properly

Tags: scala, sbt

I wanted to build up Akka project.

so, I **created** build.sbt file in root folder of project, it looks like following:

```
name := "Akka Sample"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2-SNAPSHOT"
```

and typed this on console line.

The result is

```
C:\scala\work\AkkaSample>sbt update

C:\scala\work\AkkaSample>set SCRIPT_DIR=C:\sbt\

C:\scala\work\AkkaSample>java -Xmx512M -jar "C:\sbt\sbt-launch.jar" update
[info] Building project AkkaSamples 1.0 against Scala 2.9.0
[info]    using sbt.DefaultProject with sbt 0.7.7 and Scala 2.7.7
[info]
[info] == update ==
[warn] No dependency configuration found, using defaults.
[info] :: retrieving :: com.dohyeon#akkasamples_2.9.0 [sync]
[info]  confs: [default]
[info]  0 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (0kB/51ms)
[info] == update ==
[success] Successful.
[info]
[info] Total time: 1 s, completed 2013. 6. 13 오후 6:30:51
[info]
[info] Total session time: 1 s, completed 2013. 6. 13 오후 6:30:51
[success] Build completed successfully.
```

You may noticed that I setted scalaVersion as 2.10.1, but sbt built Sacla 2.9.0

It seems like sbt tool dosen't work properly.

I tried to find a solution, but due to I am not a native English speaker and I am not familiar with English, so I could not find a solution...

Please let me grab a solution, Thanks.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Which version of `sbt` are you using? Also, which version of Scala is on your `PATH`?

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is update sbt and then try again. 0.7.7 is a pretty old version. The current version is 0.12.3. Here are the instructions how to install the newer version: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup#installing-sbt

Comment: @Christian I agree. Especially if this is a new project.